# ¿Qué código HTTP puedo utilizar?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, api, restful

estoy creando una API REST y me encontré con un tema confuso.
Tengo un recurso para buscar un usuario por id que devuelve un json con toda la información del usuario. Que códigos http puedo usar para cuando un usuario está invisible y cuando no tenga membresía? Puedo usar un código 200 y pasarle como mensaje el error?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Status

Comment: El recurso se encuentra, pero al validar si está invisible o si no tiene membresía debería darte el código de error.

Comment: En el enlace que te pase, en la familia de los 400, esta esto: **403 Forbidden
El cliente no posee los permisos necesarios para cierto contenido, por lo que el servidor está rechazando otorgar una respuesta apropiada.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El codigo [403 forbidden](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403) es utilizando exactamente para esto:

> El código de error de respuesta HTTP 403 Forbidden indica que el
> servidor ha entendido nuestra petición, pero se niega a autorizarla.
> Este estado es similar a 401, pero en este caso, re-autenticarnos no
> provocará ninguna diferencia. El acceso está permanentemente prohibido
> y vinculado a la lógica de la aplicación (como un error de contraseña
> incorrecta)

.